# Adding maven nexus repo to my pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have installed nexus on my local machine. I want my pom file to point to this repo. How can I add my custom repository to my pom.xml file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From [Maven - Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#servers)

The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the `repositories` and `distributionManagement` elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>server001</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

**id:** This is the ID of the server (not of the user to login as) that matches the id element of the repository/mirror that Maven tries to connect to.

**username, password:** These elements appear as a pair denoting the login and password required to authenticate to this server.

**privateKey, passphrase:** Like the previous two elements, this pair specifies a path to a private key (default is `${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa`) and a passphrase, if required. The passphrase and password elements may be externalized in the future, but for now they must be set plain-text in the settings.xml file.

**filePermissions, directoryPermissions:** When a repository file or directory is created on deployment, these are the permissions to use. The legal values of each is a three digit number corrosponding to *nix file permissions, ie. 664, or 775.

**Note:** If you use a private key to login to the server, make sure you omit the  element. Otherwise, the key will be ignored.

**All you should need is the `id`, `username` and `password`**

The `id` and `URL` should be defined in your `pom.xml` like this:

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>acme-nexus-releases</id>
        <name>acme nexus</name>
        <url>https://nexus.acme.net/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    ...
</repositories>
```

If you need a username and password to your server, you should encrypt it.
[Maven Password Encryption](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)

Answer (score 22):

First of all I can highly recommend reading the [Nexus book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/). It will explain the benefits of using a Maven repository manager.

There is a section on how to configure your Maven build to use Nexus:

- http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config.html

This leads me to question why you altering your POM file? I suspect what you really want to do is setup Nexus as a remote repository mirror. This is done in your Maven settings file.

The following tells Maven use Nexus as your default repository (Instead of [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/))

```xml
<settings>
  ..
  ..
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

This is desired behaviour since your Nexus repository is configured to cache artifacts retrieved from Central (which is good for build performance).

Note:

- The "public" repository group could include other repositories proxied by your Nexus instance (Not just Maven Central). You probabily want this behaviour, as it centralizes all repository management. It just makes your build less portable for people outside of your organization.

Answer (score 10):

It seems the answers here do not support an enterprise use case where a Nexus server has multiple users and has project-based isolation (protection) based on user id ALONG with using an automated build (CI) system like Jenkins. You would not be able to create a settings.xml file to satisfy the different user ids needed for different projects. I am not sure how to solve this, except by opening Nexus up to anonymous access for reading repositories, unless the projects could store a project-specific generic user id in their pom.xml.

Comment: +1 -- Correct. The other comments on the page are not thinking out of the box or completely misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: @kevin-buchs why don't you create one _settings.xml_ file per project, and explicitly link to the right one from the Jenkins job with _mvn clean install -s projectA-settings.xml_?

Comment: Or have the Jenkins job create the settings.xml specifically for each build with credentials from Jenkins credentials store and using the right repositories for the particular department/team/etc

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want or you cannot modify the `settings.xml` file, you can create a new one at the root of your project, and call maven passing it as a parameter with the `-s` argument:

```
$ mvn COMMAND ... -s settings.xml
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [Apache Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

"The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the repositories and distributionManagement elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml." - [Apache Maven site - settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>server001</id>
        <username>my_login</username>
        <password>my_password</password>
        <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
        <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [maven setting reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html), you can not put your username/password in a pom.xml

> The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the repositories and distributionManagement elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml.

You can first add a repository in your pom and then add the username/password in the $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml:

```xml
  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-internal-site</id>
        <username>yourUsername</username>
        <password>yourPassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Comment: Not necessarily true. You may be able to put it in either your POM or your settings.xml. Whether one should put it there is a matter of opinion related to the particular use case. The statement "can not" is reading opinion into the Maven Settings Reference.

Comment: It's possible add credentials (username and password) to pom.xml as variables/env vars and set externally their values?

Comment: @ingyhere how can I put server credentials in pom.xml, as you say? [Maven 4 schema](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) does not support the `servers` element and I can't figure out how I could put my username and password there.

Comment: @MauroMolinari The use case for creds in a POM usually have to do with non-Java devs not wanting a settings file on their local box because they aren't remote repo users. Today, I'd no longer accommodate such a request and insist on one. (I don't believe this older comment aged well with documentation updates.) However, there are a number of solutions that range from (possibly) build plugins to feeding in values with `-D` flags or even re-defining property placeholders in `settings.xml` within the POM. Also, possibly, consider the `https://username:password@URL` scheme in `repositories` block.

Comment: @MauroMolinari Another option is creating a custom group "installer" for Maven that pre-includes a shared settings.xml file. Shared creds are a bane for sysadmins but one could also include placeholders with instructions to generate and update tokens. Maven supports the `settings.xml` file stored within the Maven installation itself at `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml` so it's just a matter of injecting that into the Maven archive before distributing it to the group.