# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:2.4

Tags: maven-3

Thanks to a Dropwizard Maven archetype I generated a sample Dropwizard Maven project. The pom.xml notably uses maven-source-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>attach-sources</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run "clean install" I have the following error :

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

The "maven-source-plugin" dependency is stored in the Nexus repository of my company. So I tried the adding of the plugin dependency between dependencies and /dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

but it did not correct the problem. I also tried to add the dependency at the call of the plugin :

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>attach-sources</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
          </dependency>
     </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```

but it did not work either

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two possible situations :

- Your company uses a proxy to connect to the public Maven repository. Then ask someone in your company what the IP address of the proxy is then put it in your settings.xml file
- Your company has its/their own Maven repository/ies (Nexus repository for example). Then ask someone in your company what the Nexus repository is then put it in your pom.xml or in your settings.xml. See [Adding maven nexus repo to my pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333577/adding-maven-nexus-repo-to-my-pom-xml) and https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 13):

It may happen, e.g. after an interrupted download, that Maven cached *a broken version* of the referenced package in your local repository.

**Solution**: Manually delete the folder of this plugin from cache (i.e. your local repository), and repeat `maven install`.

How to find the right folder? Folders in Maven repository follow the structure:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

is cached in `${USER_HOME}\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-source-plugin\2.4`

Comment: Thank you. I have been banging my head on my desk trying to figure out the reason. As it turns out, it was just an interrupted download. I cleared that repository folder, and it's all fine again.

Comment: Hi @naXa,
I facing same issue, after deleting folder inside .m2, i tried to execute mvn install- which doesn't resolve my issue. for more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773311/wso2-custom-connector-build-failure-by-using-apache-maven-3-8-4

Answer (score 4):

Update the apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0\conf\settings.xml file.

Check your internet explorer proxy --> Setting --> Internet explorer -->Connection --> LAN Setting

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>user</username>
  <password>****</password>
  <host>proxy</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using JDK 7 for maven project and I used -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 as argument in JRE. It has allowed to download all maven repository which were failing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the content of the folder `\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resource-plugin\2.7`. The cached info turned out to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin` does not exist in the repository http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

You have to download it from Maven central where it exists =>  [`maven-source-plugin`](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22maven-source-plugin%22)

Verify your pom definition or your settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

so I am assuming that this project you are doing in your private eclipse (not company provided eclipse where you work). The same problem I resolved just as below

quick fix : got to .m2 file --> create a backup of settings.xml --> remove settings.xml --> restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

On my side it was coming from an error in my settings.xml file.
I had a bad  tag. Just removed it, refreshed and i was good to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
I use intelliJ and finally I created my own settings.xml and added the following content structure to it. In my project's pom.xml, the nexus repositories were defined but for some reason it was always hitting the external apache maven repo which is blocked in my company.

<settings>
  <mirrors>
     <id>nexus</id>
     <url>nexusURL </url>
     <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    <mirror>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <repositories>
      <repository>

</settings>
```

Comment: This is invalid XML - you're missing a bunch of closing tags.

Comment: If you're developer then you'd be able to update the xml appropriately.

Comment: The same logic applies to you. There is no benefit to you leaving invalid XML when you are aware that it is invalid.

Comment: This forum is not for seeking technical consulting, it's to get the hints for smart people. @takendarkk is in the wrong forum then.