# Failed to create Maven project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm a neewbie on the Maven. 
I need use it for develop a Spring application in Java. For that I use Eclipse IDE Java EE, I downloaded Maven 3.5.3 [here](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) and I execute steps of website.

I added the configuration proxy in the .m2/settings.xml and I enter the command "mvn -v" in the Windows DOS command.
[command mvn -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQPPZ.png)

In Eclipse : File -> New -> Maven Project.

- I check "Create a simple project" and "Use default Workspace location" -> Next
- I enter a Group Id and Artifact Id / Version : 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and Packaging : jar --> Finish

Unfortunately the project not create :

[Failed to create project 'test'1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRUBj.png)

[Failed to create project 'test' 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6wte.png)

But I don't understand why I have this issue.

I try the second method with the command line, I follow this [tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/organisez-et-packagez-une-application-java-avec-apache-maven/creez-votre-premier-projet-maven?_sm_au_=iVVS6vfv5FTfDVJf) but I don't also create a project.
[Command failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYM6S.png)

Do you know why I have this error and/or the solution ?

Can you help me ? Thanks ! ☺

Cordially.

*Excuse me for my bad english.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589002/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-for-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-source-plu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

OR 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-archetype?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I would advise to stay away from the IDE (Eclipse IntelliJ or whatever) when trying Maven at least at the start. Why ? because enterprise proxy can lead to many problem and it is always more reproducible to do something by command line and you have good error logs.
Talking about error logs, I think you could provide a bit more logs regarding the command line build failed. It may help.

Comment: Since you have unresolved dependencies there is an easy thing to try which cannot hurt and may help: [1] Select your project node in **Project Explorer** [2] Right click and select **Maven > Update Project...** from the context menu [3] Check the option **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases** and click **OK**. That will force Maven to check for any resources that are missing or out of date.

Comment: Also, note that although you have downloaded version 3.5.3 of Maven,  Eclipse will not use that version by default; it will use its own embedded version instead. To get Eclipse to use your version: **Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations**, then click the **Add...** button and navigate to the location where you installed Maven 3.5.3.