# Use Maven behind Proxy

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans, proxy

I'm trying to set up a Maven project with NetBeans on a machine behind a proxy.

When I try to build the dependencies, I get the following error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved:  Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.6:  Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:  PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

[As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589002/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-for-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-source-plu), it's probably because of my proxy configuration.

Netbeans itself has access to the internet. Loading plugins etc. works:
[image: netbeans proxy]

A possible solution would be setting the proxy settings in `settings.xml`:

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>user</username>
  <password>****</password>
  <host>proxy</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

However, as the proxy configuration is set globaly, I don't have access to the parameters (user, password, etc.).

Is there any way, to get Maven to using the global proxy, as NetBeans already does, without asking the admin?

Comment: You should configre an https proxy cause access to central is via https...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Yes, but the problem is, I don't know the proxy settings. I'm not using my **own** machine.