# WSO2 Custom Connector Build Failure by using apache-maven-3.8.4

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have tried to create custom connector by following this [WSO2 Documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/customizations/creating-new-connector/)

Prerequisites of apache-maven-3.8.4-bin installation done.

Connector:
[image: connector]

[image: connector 2]

maven build:

[image: build command]

ERROR:

[image: ERROR]

partial pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <connector.name>googleBooks</connector.name>
        <integration.base.version>1.0.2</integration.base.version>
        <product.ei.version>6.1.1</product.ei.version>
        <carbon.kernel.version>4.4.17</carbon.kernel.version>
        <automation.framework.utils.version>4.4.2</automation.framework.utils.version>
        <automation.framework.version>4.4.3</automation.framework.version>
        <emma.version>2.1.5320</emma.version>
        <synapse.version>2.1.7-wso2v19</synapse.version>
        <carbon.mediation.version>4.6.19</carbon.mediation.version>
        <json.version>2.0.0.wso2v1</json.version>
        <org.testng.version>6.1.1</org.testng.version>
        <jets3t.version>0.9.4</jets3t.version>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.55</bouncycastle.version>
        <rampart.apache.version>1.6.1-wso2v18</rampart.apache.version>
        <rampart.wso2.version>1.6.1.wso2v18</rampart.wso2.version>
        <skip-tests>true</skip-tests>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>${synapse.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note**: synapse-core dependency is presented in above pom.xml

What tried so far:

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589002/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-for-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-source-plu) i tried to delete below mentioned folder and run `mvn install` which also not resolving issue.

```
.m2\repository\org\apache\synapse\synapse-core\2.1.7-wso2v19
```

Can anyone please let me know the solution to resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Michael-O,

Just now i posted question 15mins back, i thought to include dependency inside pom.xml, but pom.xml already having that dependency (ie synapse-core) and added pom.xml snippet in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change in pom.xml file, in the repository nodes, url adresses. You can use find/replace like below.

from: `<url>http://maven.wso2.`...

to: `<url>https://maven.wso2.`...

From the Maven 3.8.1, it is blocking `http` mirror repositories, and uses only https adreses. More in this [Release Notes – Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html)

Comment: Hi @tmoasz,

Thank you so much for your suggestion which helped me to resolve this issue. after made url change as https instead of http in pom.xml, i can successfully build connector and got zipped file in target directory too.